# must max of sum lie in convex subspace?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

$f$ and $g$ are two concave functions defined on a convex subset $A$ of a vector space. Each of $f$ and $g$ achieves its maximum on a convex subset $B$ of $A$. Does it imply that the maximum of $f+g$ also must lie in $B$?

I think the max of the sum need not lie in the subspace. $f$ and $g$ could cancel each other out worse on the subspace where they achieve a maximum, than outside the subspace. I did not find a concrete example.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can construct counter examples where the maximum of $f+g$ is obtained outside of $\mathbf{B}$.

Consider $\mathbf{A}$ be $x,y$ such that $x^2+y^2\leq 1$. And consider $f(x,y)=x$, and $g(x,y)=y$.

Comment: Thanks but what is $B$ in your answer?